# Problems with insert enumeration in Postgresql

Tags: java, postgresql, dropwizard

I would like to make a login system in JAVA for my application with OAuth2.
But first I have to create an account and insert into my database.

This is my enumeration table:

```
CREATE TYPE userRole AS ENUM ('ADMIN');
```

And this is my user table:

```
CREATE TABLE "users"
(
    user_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    user_email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    user_password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    user_role userRole
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX user_user_email_uindex ON "user" (user_email);
```

This application used dropwizard with a dbi database connection.
When i run my code and execute my SQL query, the application throws a 500 error with the following messages:

> The column index is out of range: 3, number of columns: 2.
>
> Exception while binding 'userRole'

This is the structure of my model (user):

```
@JsonCreator
public User(@JsonProperty("userEmail") String userEmail, @JsonProperty("userPassword") String userPassword, @JsonProperty("userRole") UserRole userRole) {
    this.userEmail = userEmail;
    this.userPassword = userPassword;
    this.userRole = userRole;
}
```

Structure ResultSetMapper:

```
public class UserMapper implements ResultSetMapper<User>{

@Override
public User map(int i, ResultSet rs, StatementContext sc) throws SQLException {
    return new User(rs.getLong("user_id"), rs.getString("user_email"), rs.getString("user_password"), UserRole.ADMIN);
}      
}
```

Structure: UserDAO

```
@RegisterMapper(UserMapper.class)
public interface UserDAO {

@SqlUpdate("INSERT INTO users(user_email, user_password, user_role) VALUES(:userEmail, :userPassword, :userRole::userRole)")
void create(@BindBean User user); 
}
```

Also I have a enumeration class:

```
public enum UserRole {
ADMIN;
```

}

Can anybody help me with my problem

Kind regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a typo in your query correct it like this:

```
  @SqlUpdate("INSERT INTO users(user_email, user_password, user_role) VALUES(:userEmail, :userPassword, :userRole)")
```

And create the table with column `user_role`  the type of `VARCHAR(255)` like this:

```
   CREATE TABLE "users"
    (
user_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
user_email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
user_password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
user_role VARCHAR(255)
   );
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I try your SQL update but its not working. This is the error messages : ERROR: column "user_role" is of type userrole but expression is of type character varying. Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.